# Best practice power on/off switching with small switch in power electronic

Tags: mosfet, relay, power-electronics, switching

I am developing an industrial project as an amateur but I have no experience in power electronics.

I want to add an on/off button to a PCB design with 12-36V operating voltage and 3A load current. The switch will be positioned away from the PCB (approximately 20cm) and I will make the connection with a cable. I will also use a switch with a low current rating (300mA) and therefore the load current should not pass through the cable and switch.

I have never used power electronics components such as relays and MOSFETs. I can't decide how to act. What are the approaches in such a situation? What are the pros and cons? Please note that the input may vary between 12-36V.

Comment: Solid state relays with control circuits that accept 4-48V or so are pretty common.  They require heatsinks if the current is more than a few amps but it shouldn't be difficult to find one that can run with no heatsink at 3A.  Depending on your load, they might need diode suppression.

Comment: At 3A the MOSFETs should not get warm unless under sized or not driven properly. I used some solid state relays rated for about 35A and they were under $5.00 US.l With 8 Amps they barely got warm. They were from my favorite china supplier.